# Why cannot i use batch XCOPY while running in admin mode?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line, xcopy

i have run very simple script: 
`xcopy some.exe c:\folder\ /h/y` and it works normally. but when i try to run .bat file with this code as administrator - cmd line opens for a moment but nothing happens (file not copied). Can anyone explain this issue?

i also tried to use `echo xcopy` instead of `xcopy`, but nothing had changed.

i need only admin running of .bat file, cause i want to copy file in \windows\system32 folder

Comment: Start cmd.exe as admin then call jour batch you may see the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you start a batchfile as administrator, it's working directory is `C:\windows\system32\`. So your script doesn't find your file. Either work with absolute paths, or change the working directory.

You can change it to the directory, where your batchfile resides with:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

Note: to keep the window open to read any errormessages, append a `pause` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this completely help to solve my problem